# Page Background Cutting when resizing browser

Tags: html, css

I don't know the best way to ask this question, I am having a problem with a website I am making for a school project that is about saving Skymall. Beside the point, I am having a problem with my page which is when I resize the browser window, it permanently re-sizes the height of the background. For example:

1. I open the website
2. Then I proceed to re-size the browser
3. Finally, I put the browser back to full screen, but the background image only covers the first part of the webpage and you can scroll down freely past it.

demo here: [invisonal.com/demo](http://www.invisional.com/demo)

Some snippets of my CSS:

```
    .bg {
    position: absolute;
    height: 250%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
}

.ibg-bg {
    position: absolute;
}

#main {
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
```

What causes this? Also one final question how should I share my code to you guys. The CSS file and HTML are fairly large and I'm not sure where it is in the file. May I upload the code to dropbox or something?

Thanks guys :)

Comment: What browser and OS are u using and could you test it on other browsers ? Ok i did miss the scrolling part.

Comment: Perhaps you can add the relevant parts of the file. If you could copy paste the portion of css that styles your background, and the html that defines it, that may be helpful.

Comment: I see a problem that you listen to resize event and add .ibg-bg height as outer window height.

Comment: Hello! Sorry for such a late response, I have tried this with Google Chrome and IE on Windows 7 and Google Chrome on Windows 8.1. and I will do that J.

Comment: Kristaps thank you so much for your help! That indeed fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i commented out resize part and background remains full size after resize

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".bg").interactive_bg();
   $("#btns").interactive_bg({
     strength: 10,
     scale: 1.15,
     contain: false,
     wrapContent: true
   });
});

/*$(window).resize(function() {
  $(".wrapper > .ibg-bg").css({
    width: $(window).outerWidth(),
    height: $(window).outerHeight()
  })
})*/
```